# Converting .pdf to .jpg and displaying on site using Imagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I'm trying to convert a user-uploaded PDF file to .jpg, to create some sort of thumbnail. I want the thumbnail to be displayed on the same page once they upload their PDF.

I'm using Imagick.

Here's some of my code:

```php
$filePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$pdfThumb = new Imagick();
$pdfThumb->setResolution(300,300);
$pdfThumb->readImage($filePath . '[0]');
$pdfThumb->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$fp = $fileName . '.jpg';
$pdfThumb->writeImage($fp);
```

I don't feel like anything is really happening, and I want to make sure it saves the thumbnail to my server (possibly temporarily) and show it on a div. Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can verify the return value of the functions you are invoking. Also, make sure you've enabled full error reporting.

Comment: Error reporting is enabled now, but I'm not getting any. I just noticed it's being added to my server's root folder. Could I use writeImage() to save it to a different location?

Comment: So it's working fine after all? (Yes, I'd suggest you don't dump runtime data in the same directory as your code, just create a dedicated directory.)

Comment: It does save converted files to my server, yes. I'll go ahead and make a directory for my files now. Is there a way to delete the PDFs after they're converted? unlink?

Comment: Yes, `unlink()` can remove files.